# What are these ports on my GIGABYTE GeForce GT 1030 GPU?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

I recently bought a GeForce GT 1030 from Amazon, and I was wondering what the circled ports in the following picture are used for.  [image: Here is the picture with the ports circled]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Obviously I don't know much due to the fact it says new contributor.  Thanks for your help I guess.

Comment: @Appleoddity While that may be true, it does remind me of how many times I've seen users at work who are using the DVI port on the computer, a DVI cable, and a monitor with VGA and DVI ports, yet they still insist on using a DVI to VGA converter for no other reason than "that's the monitor plug".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one on the left in the image is either a DisplayPort connector or a HDMI connector; I'm not sure which. The one on the right is a DVI (Digital Video Interface) for a single DVI-capable monitor. You could have determined this on your own with a little research; Google suggested I check https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-1030/specifications, which had the info.

EDIT: https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/feature/digital-home/displayport-vs-hdmi-3535257/ seems to imply that the left port is HDMI.

Comment: thanks.  So does that mean I need a VGA to DVI converter for this to function, or can I use HDMI instead?

Comment: Whether you need a converter depends on your monitor. Most recent monitors will support two or three different interfaces, so that you don't need converters.

Comment: Right, my monitor only has VGA and DVI, but I don't have any DVI cords at home.  So I'd have to buy a converter or a DVI cord, right?

Comment: No, you'd have to go buy a DVI cable - they're available pretty much for the asking; I get mine at MicroCenter. That port is a "single-link" DVI port, which means you can only connect one DVI monitor, so you want to ask for the appropriate cable - and make sure that you have the right connector at the monitor end, too. Don't get involved with conversion if you can avoid it.

Comment: @19tknight or buy a DVI cable. I recommend buying a DVI cable instead of a converter. It should be a very slightly cleaner picture, Plus I don't see the required pins on your card for the DVI to vga converter, it may be digital only.

Comment: Visually, the right port is a **dual-link** DVI-D [whether it's wired dual is considerably harder to tell] but note it's DVI-**D** not DVI-**I** [it is missing the 4 analog pins either side of the flat pin] so conversion to VGA wouldn't be straightforward. Recommended would be a DVI-D to DVI-D cable; pretty cheap these days, but you'd have to double-check the monitor can use the 'D' of DVI-D.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Specs (the GEForce URI I posted) says it's single. The dual I have on a decommissioned box next to me has a flat pin vertical crossing the horizontal flat pin (plus the four analog pins).

Comment: OK, I see it on the spec - but I think you are confusing the visual pin-out & what it tells you - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface